# Trying to change the << operator for a polynomial class

Tags: c++

This is where I am taking over the operator. I commented and put in text script and its the `cout << coeff[i] << ...` line that keeps crashing the program. Is it the operator that is crashing or should I look elsewhere?

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& output, const Poly& p)
{
    cout << "This Polynomial is ";
    for (int i = 0; i <= Poly::MAXIMUM_DEGREE; i ++)
    {
        if (coeff[i] != 0)
        {
            if (i != Poly::MAXIMUM_DEGREE)
            {
                cout << coeff[i] << "x^" << i << " + ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << coeff[i] << "x^" << i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. It should not be silent when compiling this.

Comment: Where do you set the variable `coeff`?

Comment: You're not using either parameter to the function or returning anything.  I assume `coeff` is a global somewhere you didn't show us?

Comment: the variable is set in the class.cpp file... and half the code is prewritten for the class to write the rest from

Comment: Why are you printing a global variable instead of something related to `p`?

Comment: And why are you writing to `cout` instead of `output`?

Comment: Thanks it was because of the global variable instead of using p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to note is that `operator <<` is *not* a member function. It takes `Poly` as a parameter, not as an implicit `this` pointer. This should explain the compile error: `coeff` is a member of `p`, so it should be accessed through `p`, i.e. like this: `p.coeff`.

Assuming that `coeff` is a private member, you need to make `operator <<` a `friend` of the `Poly` class.

```
output << p.coeff[i] << "x^" << i << " + ";
```

Comment: /OT Would you mind sharing your preferred crystal balls vendors address? I'd like to purchase some. That's a serious request.;-)

Answer (score 2):

`operator<<()` needs to write to `output`, not to `cout`.   It also needs to return `output`, so the stream operators can be chained.   By not returning anything, you cause the caller to have undefined behaviour on something as simple as `some_stream << some_poly << ' ' << some_other_poly;`

When a caller uses the operator, it will specify what `output` is.  For example, `std::cout << some_poly` will write `some_poly` to `std::cout`, while `some_stream << some_poly` will write it to `some_stream`.   As you've implemented it, all usage of the streaming operator will write to `cout` and not to any other stream, whether the caller wants that or not.

Also, usually, it should be the caller that decides whether or not to output anciliary information, such as a string `"This Polynomial is "`.   The streaming operator should focus solely on outputting the object.   If, for example, you want to output "This Polynomal is " and then output "That Polynomial is ", let the caller make that decision (and output what additional information is needed).   Don't try to hard-code that information into the streaming operator, as it prevents that sort of flexibility for the caller.

Comment: cout is what my class was shown to use considering most of us had never touched C++ before.